# Execute a file AS .exe while it does not have a .exe extension

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

I need this for very specific reasons.

Example of what i want:

rename notepad.exe to notepad.test and have a way of opening it as .exe later.

i can't rename them.

Comment: No way to do it directly, especailly when the non-EXE extension you use is registered one (have some handler in your OS). Special script or app starting those file as executable one is needed.

Comment: @Akina: Depends on how "directly" you want it... File extensions and their handlers are only important to the graphical shell (things like Explorer and ShellExecute()). Anything which _directly_ calls CreateProcess() will run any file regardless of name, like cmd.exe in Franck's answer below.

Comment: @grawity *Depends on how "directly" you want it...* The author said: *a way of opening it*. Not start, not run. Open. Additionally he marks the question with the [windows-explorer] tag. *like cmd.exe in Franck's answer below* I tries the method in Franck's answer below... without success.

Comment: Can I ask _why_ you want to do this? This seems like an xy problem.  What's wrong with "notepad.test.exe"?

Comment: @baldrickk I want to execute something, and it not be listed on any of the Nirsoft Tools.

Answer (score 4):

> rename notepad.exe to notepad.test and have a way of opening it as .exe later.

You can run `notepad.test` from the [Command Prompt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe), and probably most other command-line interpreters / shells.

E.g.:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++>"notepad++.test"
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe you'll show the command for the command prompt which starts renamed `c:\notepad.test` as executable?

Comment: @Akina The command is `notepad.test`

Comment: Have you tested it? or you THINK it is to work? I have tested it on Win XP,7,10 - without success - 'notepad.test is not built-in or external command, executable or batch file' (indirect translation of cmd's message). Procmon shows CreateFile and QueryDirectory calls and does not show CreateProcess or ShellExecute ones...

Comment: @Akina I tested on Microsoft Windows 7. You need to cd to wherever `notepad.test` is located first.

Comment: Of course I did it. But neither changing current drive/path, nor specifying them in the command line helps... on Win 7 & 10 on my station I see the same as on your screenshot, but nothing starts, on Win XP I see the message posted above :(. On another station with Win 7 - it starts... maybe some additional OS settings are wrong (something like DEP...)? I'll test.

Comment: @Akina Interesting, I wasn't aware of this. Maybe I got lucky :)

Comment: Sadly, i think this does not work. Tested it multiple times and the executable does not open.

Comment: @insidepug perhaps some operating systems are configured differently. It works fine on my Microsoft Windows 7, and I haven't changed anything to make it work.

Comment: when you say, "works fine", you mean the program opens and works properly?

Comment: @insidepug yes.